# How to configure Custom Url when Session Invalidation occurs

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3 and my ApplicationContext-Security.xml specifies

```
 <form-login login-page="/genesis" default-target-url="/diagnostics/start-diagnostics"
      authentication-failure-url="/genesis?authfailed=true"
      authentication-success-handler-ref="customTargetUrlResolver"/>
      <access-denied-handler error-page="/genesis?notauthorized=true"/>

     <logout logout-success-url="/genesis"/> 

    <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/genesis"> 
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
    </session-management>
```

However when I log into my app in a second browser, then return to my first browser as soon as I try to do anything I get a plain white screen with the message "This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user"

How do I configure Spring Security 3 to display my own "you've been disconnected" URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either:

- force concurrency filter to throw authentication exception (and it'll be handled by `<form-login>`),
- provide your own session-expired page.

These situations are described [here in Spring Security manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-concurrency-control):

> `<concurrency-control>` Attributes
>
> `error-if-maximum-exceeded`
>
> If set to "true" a SessionAuthenticationException will be raised when
>   a user attempts to exceed the maximum allowed number of sessions. The
>   default behaviour is to expire the original session.
>
> `expired-url`
>
> The URL a user will be redirected to if they attempt to use a session
>   which has been "expired" by the concurrent session controller because
>   the user has exceeded the number of allowed sessions and has logged in
>   again elsewhere. Should be set unless exception-if-maximum-exceeded is
>   set. If no value is supplied, an expiry message will just be written
>   directly back to the response.

Also check [ConcurrentSessionFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/session/ConcurrentSessionFilter.html) and [ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html) for more details.

---

**Answering your question**: in your config you should have something like this:

```
<session-management session-authentication-error-url="/genesis"> 
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/sessionExpired.jsp" />
</session-management>
```

*Note that `expired-url` is not the same as `session-authentication-error-url`.*

Comment: What is meant by "an expiry message will just be written directly back to the response"? It is just an error?

Comment: @zygimantus Here it means that if you don't set `expired-url`, Spring Security will return HTTP response with some message, nothing more - no redirects etc.