# spring security set expired-url

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Java configuration in my Spring MVC application. I need to **configure `expired-url` with java config (not XML config)**. I found this piece of XML from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083356/1531130):

```
<session-management> 
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/expired" />
</session-management>
```

But I don't know how can I convert this structure to Java config. I tried this code but it's not working:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/expired")
        .and()
        ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .expiredUrl("/expired")
        .and()
        ... 
}
```

Comment: I tested it, but not working. Still when the session times out, users redirect to login page, not `/expired`.

Comment: Getting the same problem. Any solution